# nautilus: how to show column "modified - time" by default

Tags: nautilus

I wish to show the column "modified - time" in nautilus. I know I can do so by right-clicking the title line and selecting the appropriate item. However, this setting only applies to the folder where I make it; when I open another folder, I must do it again, so I wish to change the default.

I also know I can set the default of the columns to be shown by using the dconf-editor's panel gnome/nautilus/list-view/default-visible-columns. In this panel, the names of the desired columns must be entered as strings. Most of the strings to be entered there are sufficiently self-explaining; however I cannot figure out what string I have to add to obtain the "modified-time" column. Does anybody know?

Imho a full list of what strings are expected in this panel and what they stand for would be appreciated by all of its users.

Answer (score 1):

My attention has been drawn to the fact that the desired defaults can also be set in Nautilus's preferences dialog, and that there is no need at all to use dconf-editor for this purpose.

After setting "modified - time" in the preferences dialog, I see in dconf-editor that what I would have had to enter there is 'date_modified_with_time' - in fact no easy guess.

Comment: I asked this question a month ago and now gave the answer that I consider to be the correct one, in cas someone else is interested. What do I have to do to flag the item as solved?

Comment: To mark the question as solved, Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks for posting